# Does the value of the gift I give Nami effect the amount of affection I gain from it?

Tags: harvest-moon-a-wonderful-life

In *Harvest Moon: A Wonderful Life*, does the amount of value a gift to Nami (or one of the other two girls) effect how quickly you get hearts?

For example, she likes homemade food, does the value of the the food effect how much she likes it? Ditto artifacts and flowers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A Wonderful Life* is like the other Harvest Moon games in that gaining relationship points from gifts depends entirely on what the gift is. Nami likes home-cooked food (except for Failed Dishes) and those will increase her relationship points by the same amount, no matter what that dish is.